# How to do dynamic creation of per-process queues in Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to dynamically create multiple `Process`es, where each instance has a queue for incoming messages from other instances, and each instance can also create new instances. So we end up with a network of processes all sending to each other. Every instance is allowed to send to every other.

The code below *would* do what I want: it uses a `Manager.dict()` to store the queues, making sure updates are propagated, and a `Lock()` to protect write-access to the queues. However when adding a new queue it throws `"RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance"`.

The problem is that when starting-up, we don't know how many queues will eventually be needed, so we have to create them dynamically. But since we can't share queues except at construction time, I don't know how to do that.

I know that one possibility would be to make `queues` a global variable instead of a managed one passed-in to `__init__`: the problem then, as I understand it, is that additions to the `queues` variable wouldn't be propagated to other processes.

**EDIT** I'm working on evolutionary algorithms. EAs are a type of machine learning technique. An EA simulates a "population", which evolves by survival of the fittest, crossover, and mutation. In *parallel* EAs, as here, we also have migration between populations, corresponding to interprocess communication. Islands can also spawn new islands, and so we need a way to send messages between dynamically-created processes.

```
import random, time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Lock, Manager, current_process
try:
    from queue import Empty as EmptyQueueException
except ImportError:
    from Queue import Empty as EmptyQueueException

class MyProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, queues, lock):
        super(MyProcess, self).__init__(target=lambda x: self.run(x),
                                     args=tuple())
        self.queues = queues
        self.lock = lock
        # acquire lock and add a new queue for this process
        with self.lock:
            self.id = len(list(self.queues.keys()))
            self.queues[self.id] = Queue()

    def run(self):
        while len(list(self.queues.keys())) < 10:

            # make a new process
            new = MyProcess(self.lock)
            new.start()

            # send a message to a random process
            dest_key = random.choice(list(self.queues.keys()))
            dest = self.queues[dest_key]
            dest.put("hello to %s from %s" % (dest_key, self.id))

            # receive messages
            message = True
            while message:
                try:
                    message = self.queues[self.id].get(False) # don't block
                    print("%s received: %s" % (self.id, message))
                except EmptyQueueException:
                    break

            # what queues does this process know about?
            print("%d: I know of %s" %
                  (self.id, " ".join([str(id) for id in self.queues.keys()])))

            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Construct MyProcess with a Manager.dict for storing the queues
    # and a lock to protect write access. Start.
    MyProcess(Manager().dict(), Lock()).start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your use case actually is here.  Perhaps if you elaborate a bit more on why you want to have each process dynamically spawn a child with a connected queue it'll be a bit more clear what the right solution would be in this situation.

Anyway, with the question as is it seems that there is not really a good way to dynamically create pipes or queues with Multiprocessing right now.

I think that if you're willing to spawn threads within each of your processes you may be able to use `multiprocessing.connection.Listener/Client` to communicate back and forth.  Rather than spawning threads I took an approach using network sockets and select to communicate between threads.

Dynamic process spawning and network sockets may still be flaky depending on how `multiprocessing` cleans up your file descriptors when spawning/forking a new process and your solution will most likely work more easily on *nix derivatives.  If you're concerned about socket overhead you could use unix domain sockets to be a little more lightweight at the cost of added complexity running nodes on multiple worker machines.

Anyway, here's an example using network sockets and a global process list to accomplish this since I was unable to find a good way to make `multiprocessing` do it.

```
import collections
import multiprocessing
import random
import select
import socket
import time


class MessagePassingProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, id_, processes):
        self.id = id_
        self.processes = processes
        self.queue = collections.deque()
        super(MessagePassingProcess, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        print "Running"
        inputs = []
        outputs = []
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        address = self.processes[self.id]["address"]
        print "Process %s binding to %s"%(self.id, address)
        server.bind(address)
        server.listen(5)
        inputs.append(server)
        process = self.processes[self.id]
        process["listening"] = True
        self.processes[self.id] = process
        print "Process %s now listening!(%s)"%(self.id, process)
        while inputs:
            readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs,
                                                           outputs,
                                                           inputs,
                                                           0.1)
            for sock in readable:
                print "Process %s has a readable scoket: %s"%(self.id,
                                                              sock)
                if sock is server:
                    print "Process %s has a readable server scoket: %s"%(self.id,
                                                              sock)
                    conn, addr = sock.accept()
                    conn.setblocking(0)
                    inputs.append(conn)
                else:
                    data = sock.recv(1024)
                    if data:
                        self.queue.append(data)
                        print "non server readable socket with data"
                    else:
                        inputs.remove(sock)
                        sock.close()
                        print "non server readable socket with no data"

            for sock in exceptional:
                print "exception occured on socket %s"%(sock)
                inputs.remove(sock)
                sock.close()

            while len(self.queue) >= 1:
                print "Received:", self.queue.pop()

            # send a message to a random process:
            random_id = random.choice(list(self.processes.keys()))
            print "%s Attempting to send message to %s"%(self.id, random_id)
            random_process = self.processes[random_id]
            print "random_process:", random_process
            if random_process["listening"]:
                random_address = random_process["address"]
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                try:
                    s.connect(random_address)
                except socket.error:
                    print "%s failed to send to %s"%(self.id, random_id)
                else:
                    s.send("Hello World!")                    
                finally:
                    s.close()

            time.sleep(1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    print "hostname:", socket.getfqdn()
    print dir(multiprocessing)
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    processes = manager.dict()
    joinable = []
    for n in xrange(multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
        mpp = MessagePassingProcess(n, processes)
        processes[n] = {"id":n,
                        "address":("127.0.0.1",7000+n),
                        "listening":False,
                        }
        print "processes[%s] = %s"%(n, processes[n])
        mpp.start()
        joinable.append(mpp)
    for process in joinable:
        process.join()
```

With a lot of polish and testing love this might be a logical extension to `multiprocessing.Process` and/or `multiprocessing.Pool` as this does seem like something people would use if it were available in the standard lib.  It may also be reasonable to create a DynamicQueue class that uses sockets to be discoverable to other queues.

Anyway, hope it helps.  Please update if you figure out a better way to make this work.

Comment: Wow, this is really useful, thanks. I've added a little info on the use-case to the original question. The advantage of queues is not having to think about buffers, pickling, incomplete `recv`s, and so on. But I can see now that a connected queue wasn't necessary: sockets will work fine with a little extra work. I took your code and changed it: can now send objects via pickle, can create new processes, and each new process now adds *itself* to the dictionary. I'll add my code as a separate answer.

Comment: I'm really glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

This code is based on the accepted answer. It's in Python 3 since OSX Snow Leopard segfaults on some uses of multiprocessing stuff.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import collections
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Lock, cpu_count
import random
import select
import socket
import time
import pickle

class Message:
    def __init__(self, origin):
        self.type = "long_msg"
        self.data = "X" * 3000
        self.origin = origin
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %d" % (self.type, self.origin)

class MessagePassingProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, processes, lock):
        self.lock = lock
        self.processes = processes
        with self.lock:
            self.id = len(list(processes.keys()))
            process_dict = {"id": self.id,
                            "address": ("127.0.0.1", 7000 + self.id),
                            "listening": False
                            }
            self.processes[self.id] = process_dict
        print("new process: processes[%s] = %s" % (self.id, processes[self.id]))
        self.queue = collections.deque()
        super(MessagePassingProcess, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        print("Running")
        self.processes[self.id]["joinable"] = True
        inputs = []
        outputs = []
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        address = self.processes[self.id]["address"]
        print("Process %s binding to %s" % (self.id, address))
        server.bind(address)
        server.listen(5)
        inputs.append(server)
        process = self.processes[self.id]
        process["listening"] = True
        self.processes[self.id] = process
        print("Process %s now listening!(%s)" % (self.id, process))
        while inputs and len(list(self.processes.keys())) < 10:
            readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs,
                                                           outputs,
                                                           inputs,
                                                           0.1)
            # read incoming messages
            for sock in readable:
                print("Process %s has a readable socket: %s" % (self.id, sock))
                if sock is server:
                    print("Process %s has a readable server socket: %s" %
                          (self.id, sock))
                    conn, addr = sock.accept()
                    conn.setblocking(0)
                    inputs.append(conn)
                else:
                    data = True
                    item = bytes() # empty bytes object, to be added to
                    recvs = 0
                    while data:
                        data = sock.recv(1024)
                        item += data
                        recvs += 1
                    if len(item):
                        self.queue.append(item)
                        print("non server readable socket: recvd %d bytes in %d parts"
                              % (len(item), recvs))
                    else:
                        inputs.remove(sock)
                        sock.close()
                        print("non server readable socket: nothing to read")

            for sock in exceptional:
                print("exception occured on socket %s" % (sock))
                inputs.remove(sock)
                sock.close()

            while len(self.queue):
                msg = pickle.loads(self.queue.pop())
                print("received:" + str(msg))

            # send a message to a random process:
            random_id = random.choice(list(self.processes.keys()))
            print("%s attempting to send message to %s" % (self.id, random_id))
            random_process = self.processes[random_id]
            if random_process["listening"]:
                random_address = random_process["address"]
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                try:
                    s.connect(random_address)
                except socket.error:
                    print("%s failed to send to %s"%(self.id, random_id))
                else:
                    item = pickle.dumps(Message(self.id))
                    print("sending a total of %d bytes" % len(item))
                    s.sendall(item)
                finally:
                    s.close()

            # make a new process
            if random.random() < 0.1:
                mpp = MessagePassingProcess(self.processes, self.lock)
                mpp.start()
            else:
                time.sleep(1.0)
        print("process %d finished looping" % self.id)


if __name__=="__main__":
    manager = Manager()
    processes = manager.dict()
    lock = Lock()
    # make just one process: it will make more
    mpp = MessagePassingProcess(processes, lock)
    mpp.start()
    # this doesn't join on all the other processes created
    # subsequently
    mpp.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard library socketserver is provided to help avoid programming select() manually. In this version, we start a socketserver in a separate thread so that each Process can do (well, pretend to do) computation in its main loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Each Node is an mp.Process. It opens a client-side socket to send a
# message to another Node. Each Node listens using a separate thread
# running a socketserver (so avoiding manual programming of select()),
# which itself starts a new thread to handle each incoming connection.
# The socketserver puts received messages on an mp.Queue, where they
# are picked up by the Node for processing once per loop. This setup
# allows the Node to do computation in its main loop.

import multiprocessing as mp
import threading, random, socket, socketserver, time, pickle, queue

class Message:
    def __init__(self, origin):
        self.type = "long_message"
        self.data = "X" * random.randint(0, 2000)
        self.origin = origin
    def __str__(self):
        return "Message of type %s, length %d from %d" % (
            self.type, len(self.data), self.origin)

class Node(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, nodes, lock):
        super().__init__()

        # Add this node to the Manager.dict of node descriptors.
        # Write-access is protected by a Lock.
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.lock = lock
        with self.lock:
            self.id = len(list(nodes.keys()))
            host = "127.0.0.1"
            port = 7022 + self.id
            node = {"id": self.id, "address": (host, port), "listening": False}
            self.nodes[self.id] = node
        print("new node: nodes[%s] = %s" % (self.id, nodes[self.id]))

        # Set up socketserver.

        # don't know why collections.deque or queue.Queue don't work here.
        self.queue = mp.Queue()

        # This MixIn usage is directly from the python.org
        # socketserver docs
        class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn,
                                socketserver.TCPServer):
            pass
        class HandlerWithQueue(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
            # Something of a hack: using class variables to give the
            # Handler access to this Node-specific data
            handler_queue = self.queue
            handler_id = self.id
            def handle(self):
                # could receive data in multiple chunks, so loop and
                # concatenate
                item = bytes()
                recvs = 0
                data = True
                if data:
                    data = self.request.recv(4096)
                    item += data
                    recvs += 1
                if len(item):
                    # Receive a pickle here and put it straight on
                    # queue. Will be unpickled when taken off queue.
                    print("%d: socketserver received %d bytes in %d recv()s"
                          % (self.handler_id, len(item), recvs))
                    self.handler_queue.put(item)

        self.server = ThreadedTCPServer((host, port), HandlerWithQueue)
        self.server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever)
        self.server_thread.setDaemon(True) # Tell it to exit when Node exits.
        self.server_thread.start()
        print("%d: server loop running in thread %s" %
              (self.id, self.server_thread.getName()))

        # Now ready to receive
        with self.lock:
            # Careful: if we assign directly to
            # self.nodes[self.id]["listening"], the new value *won't*
            # be propagated to other Nodes by the Manager.dict. Have
            # to use this hack to re-assign the Manager.dict key.
            node = self.nodes[self.id]
            node["listening"] = True
            self.nodes[self.id] = node

    def send(self):
        # Find a destination. All listening nodes are eligible except self.
        dests = [node for node in self.nodes.values()
                 if node["id"] != self.id and node["listening"]]
        if len(dests) < 1:
            print("%d: no node to send to" % self.id)
            return
        dest = random.choice(dests)
        print("%d: sending to %s" % (self.id, dest["id"]))

        # send
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            s.connect(dest["address"])
        except socket.error:
            print("%s: failed to send to %s" % (self.id, dest["id"]))
        else:
            item = pickle.dumps(Message(self.id))
            s.sendall(item)
        finally:
            s.close()

    # Check our queue for incoming messages.
    def receive(self):
        while True:
            try:
                message = pickle.loads(self.queue.get(False))
                print("%d: received %s" % (self.id, str(message)))
            except queue.Empty:
                break

    def run(self):
        print("%d: in run()" % self.id)
        # Main loop. Loop until at least 10 Nodes exist. Because of
        # parallel processing we might get a few more
        while len(list(self.nodes.keys())) < 10:
            time.sleep(random.random() * 0.5) # simulate heavy computation
            self.send()
            time.sleep(random.random() * 0.5) # simulate heavy computation
            self.receive()
            # maybe make a new node
            if random.random() < 0.1:
                new = Node(self.nodes, self.lock)
                new.start()
        # Seems natural to call server_thread.shutdown() here, but it
        # hangs. But since we've set the thread to be a daemon, it
        # will exit when this process does.
        print("%d: finished" % self.id)

if __name__=="__main__":
    manager = mp.Manager()
    nodes = manager.dict()
    lock = mp.Lock()
    # make just one node: it will make more
    node0 = Node(nodes, lock)
    node0.start()
    # This doesn't join on all the other nodes created subsequently.
    # But everything seems to work out ok.
    node0.join()
```

Comment: It's important to note that select / socketserver are both very different models: socketserver uses threading/forking and blocking sockets while select uses a single process with non-blocking sockets.

Comment: @Mike Good point, thanks. I hope I understand right: from the listener's point of view, having non-blocking sockets in-process  has much the same effect as having blocking sockets in a dedicated process/thread: in both cases the messages end up being processed once per iteration. However from the sender's point of view, it is easier to do a "fire-and-forget" send to a *blocking* socket, since it is "guaranteed" (in reality, there are no guarantees) to be listening rather than computing in some other part of its loop.